# Dominion - Kings Court on Tragic Hero

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity, dominion-nocturne

What happens when you play a [kings court](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/King%27s_Court) on a [tragic hero](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Tragic_Hero)?

Does it go like this:
Lets say your hand is 3 coppers, a kings court and a tragic hero.

1. Play the kings court
2. Select the tragic hero
3. (Play tragic hero first time) Pick up 3 cards (now have 6 cards in hand)
4. (Play tragic hero second time) Pick up 3 cards (now have 9 cards in hand)
5. Tragic hero gets trashed for say a gold
6. (Play tragic hero third time) The effect fizzles as the tragic hero has been trashed.

Is the above correct?

Comment: The classic version of this is Throne Room and Feast, which was addressed in the original FAQ: If you use Throne Room on Feast, you will gain two cards, even though you can only trash Feast once. https://dominioncg.fandom.com/wiki/Feast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite. Effects only fail if their conditions can't be met - for example, if Tragic Hero had said "Trash this *to* gain a Treasure"<sup>[1]</sup>, then that wouldn't activate. However, instead, it goes like this:

```
Play a King's Court from your hand
- Select Tragic Hero to play 3 times
- Play Tragic Hero 1st time
  - Draw 3 cards
  - Get +1 Buy
- Play Tragic Hero 2nd time
  - Draw 3 cards
  - Get +1 Buy
  - You have more than 8 cards in hand
    - Trash Tragic Hero
    - Gain a Treasure
- Play Tragic Hero 3rd time
  - Draw 3 cards
  - Get +1 Buy
  - You have more than 8 cards in hand
    - Try to trash Tragic Hero, but you can't (it's no longer in play)[2]
    - Gain a Treasure
```

<sup>[1]</sup> "Do X to do Y." in Dominion is equivalent to "Do X. If you did, do Y." so you must do X if possible, but you only do Y if you successfully did X. "You may do X to do Y." is the same except that you choose whether to do X, then you do Y if you did X successfully.

<sup>[2]</sup> This is the [Stop-Moving rule](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Stop-Moving_rule). Tragic Hero's effect comes from being played, so it expects to find itself in play. It isn't in play, so it can't trash itself.

Comment: Note that the rules are being updated slightly to say that you can’t play a card that wouldn’t be able to be put into play; but it doesn’t affect Throne Room or King’s Court because the new rule says that a card can play a card multiple times if the first play succeeds. http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=19893.msg871558#msg871558